# How to extend standard Exception for custom messages and logging in an API?

Tags: apex, exception

I have been trying to rewrite some older api - just starting with rewrite of error messages and logging.

I saw a lot of duplicated code with error responses and logging, so I decided to separate it not only to methods, but to enhance Exception.

In small tests it worked well, but in a bigger test of calling .. static methods.. it sometime worked, sometime not. Mostly not, but I've seen also few times the test going through, with use of Exceptions. 
The error I get is some fatal error and

Internal Salesforce Error: 768769596-1131211 (-1608442117) (-1608442117)

```
public abstract class BaseAPIException extends Exception {
   public BaseAPIException(Exception e, APIStructure contact){
      this.initCause(e);
      /// something more.. 
   }
   public BaseAPIException(String message, APIStructure contact){
      this.setMessage(message);
      /// something more.. 
   }
   public Integer getStatusCode() {
       return this.statusCode;
    }
  // similarly method for response body... 
   public Blob getResponseBodyBlob(){.... 
   }
}

public class EmptyParameterException extends BaseAPIException {

   public EmptyParameterException(String message, String parameter) {
      this.setMessage(message);
      // or super(message, null)
      this.parameter = parameter;
      this.statusCode = 400;
      // or something like that.. 
   }
}
```

Yeah, I know its too complicated, there were some functionalities/different messages in some situations, but overall its nothing more than some custom messages.. It could be everything in one extending class with more different constructors (when i discovered that you cannot override basic Exception constructors.. (duh..)) so there still needs to be some mess and not just doing throw new EmptyParameterException(parameter) and it lost its simplicity purpose in writing the inheritance etc..

BAck to problem: simple test which is working:

```
try {
    throw new MyRestAPI.EmptyParameterException('parameter is empty', 'myParameter');
} catch (MyRestAPI.BaseAPIException e) {
    System.debug(e.getStatusCode());
    System.debug(e.getResponseBodyBlob());
}
```

But when running all the test with RestAPI class which is calling also some static methods in handler which propagates different exceptions and I'm trying to catch them and create my own Exceptions its getting this error...

**But!!** When I've run all the test class, only one method had an error, others passed. But when I called specifically one test method with invalid requests again, the one which passed five seconds ago, it didn't pass.

```
12:56:18.2 (669951950)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
12:56:18.2 (670087605)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
12:56:18.670 (670102200)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
12:56:18.670 (670102200)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)
  Number of SOQL queries: 10 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 64 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 8 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 8 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 244 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

12:56:18.670 (670102200)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
```

Did somebody saw something like that? When serializing exceptions through basic constructor this(message) or this.setMessage(message) or anything similar?

I'm helpless, giving up, and rewriting it in some completely simple way.

Comment: Without seeing code, all we can do is guess. For a gack ("Internal Salesforce Error"), you should contact Support, as it indicates that you're trying to do something that may not be supported (without seeing your code, all we can do is guess), or it could be a bug in the system.

Comment: I added the description with sample code and last error message and I'll write also to salesforce to get some explanation because its crazy... One time it works, other time with some limit it doesn't and I'm not able to google anything about the error, which is relevant to exceptions..

Comment: And I'm also discovering that the API was written I guess by some old bad method, because all the stuff should be covered by salesforce REST API itself I guess..Because the call of the test methods is like this: ```MyRestAPI.ProcessPost();``` 
So the method of the api itself is just ```@HttpPost
    global static void ProcessPost() {```